# How to inject activity into another class using dagger.android?

Tags: android, dagger-2, dagger

I'm using the new dagger.android method to inject activities, but I wonder what to do if you want to inject `Activity` to a class? Maybe a `Navigator` class which needs the current activity:

```
package com.abydos.messenger.ui

import android.app.Activity
import com.abydos.messenger.ui.register.RegisterActivity
import org.jetbrains.anko.startActivity
import javax.inject.Inject

class Navigator @Inject constructor(private val activity: Activity) {
    fun register() {
        activity.startActivity<RegisterActivity>()
    }

    ...
}
```

And in `ActivityBindingModule.kt`

```
package com.abydos.messenger.di

import com.abydos.messenger.ui.register.RegisterActivity
import dagger.Module
import dagger.android.ContributesAndroidInjector

@Module
abstract class ActivityBindingModule {
    @ContributesAndroidInjector
    abstract fun contributeRegisterActivity(): RegisterActivity

    ...
}
```

Maybe something like this for each activity might work?

```
@Binds abstract fun bindActivity(yourActivity: YourActivity): Activity
```

But I don't like the idea of having to write this for all activities, is there a better way?

Comment: The question is, why do you want to inject an `Activity` into another one?

Comment: have you ever find the answer ?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately dagger-android-processor don't create this binding automatically.

You need one more module:

```
@Module
interface RegisterModule {
    @Binds
    fun bindActivity(activity: RegisterActivity): Activity
}
```

And in your ActivityBindingModule:

```
@ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = arrayOf(RegisterModule::class))
abstract fun contributeRegisterActivity(): RegisterActivity
```