# How to @Inject members in BaseActivity using dagger.android?

Tags: android, dependency-injection, kotlin, dagger-2

This is my scenario:

- I want all my Activities to inherit from `BaseActivity`
- Within the `BaseActivity`, I want to inject `Navigator` (it helps me to manage the `Fragments` backstack and navigate between activities):

  ```
  abstract class BaseActivity : DaggerAppCompatActivity() {
      @Inject
      lateinit var navigator: Navigator

      @Inject
      lateinit var prefs: SharedPreferences // injected via AppModule.kt, see below.
  }
  ```
- The `Navigator` class needs a `FragmentManager` in its constructor:

  ```
  class Navigator @Inject constructor(
      val fragmentManager: FragmentManager) {
      // class body
  }
  ```
- I want to provide `FragmentManager` from a `BaseActivity` object in `BaseActivityModule`:

  ```
  @Module
  class BaseActivityModule {
      @PerActivity
      @Provides
      fun provideFragmentManager(baseActivity: BaseActivity): FragmentManager {
          return baseActivity.supportFragmentManager
      }
  }
  ```

This is the rest of my components and modules:

- **AppComponent.kt**

  ```
  @Singleton @Component(modules = [
      AndroidSupportInjectionModule::class,
      AppModule::class,
      ActivityBindingModule::class])
  interface AppComponent {
      @Component.Builder
      interface Builder {
          @BindsInstance
          fun application(application: Application): Builder
          fun build(): AppComponent
      }
      fun inject(app: AndroidApplication)
  }
  ```
- **AppModule.kt**

  ```
  @Module
  class AppModule {
      @Singleton
      @Provides
      fun providesPrefs(application: Application): SharedPreferences {
          return application.getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
      }
  }
  ```
- **ActivityBindingModule.kt**

  ```
  @Module
  abstract class ActivityBindingModule {
      @ContributesAndroidInjector
      abstract fun bindMainActivity(): MainActivity

      @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = [(BaseActivityModule::class)])
      abstract fun bindBaseActivity(): BaseActivity
  }
  ```
- **BaseActivityModule.kt**

  ```
  @Module
  class BaseActivityModule {
      @Provides
      fun provideFragmentManager(baseActivity: BaseActivity): FragmentManager {
          return baseActivity.supportFragmentManager
      }
  }
  ```

This is the compilation error message:

```
Error: [dagger.android.AndroidInjector.inject(T)]
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager cannot be provided
without an @Provides- or @Produces-annotated method.

Error:A binding with matching key exists in component:
com.myapp.ActivityBindingModule_BindBaseActivity.BaseActivitySubcomponent
```

Comment: so you want the navigator in the base activity and every activity that inherit from it ?

Comment: Yep, that's what I need.

Comment: why you need to inject at the first place you can just init it in the base activity :D          val nav = Navigator(supportFragmentManager)

Comment: and use it any activity that inherit base activity

Comment: Yep, I know. I'm just trying to do the same thing I was doing without `dagger.android`, also I think the code looks better. Haha..hope that are valid arguments.

Comment: yes the code looks better :D OK actually i will try it give me a minute to figure it out with dagger

Comment: Actually i can't find solutions for that but here why you can't achieve that in my point of you :(. your base activity added to  dagger graph using "ContributesAndroidInjector". so when you extend any activity from base activity it inherit also it's modules and competent so you need to add also to the graph. but i will try again with this problem it's interesting after i finish my work and i will inform you with the updates :D happy coding

Comment: Thanks for your time on this. Happy coding.

Comment: It may be something related to this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44268237

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem lies with your assumption that you need to inject a `BaseActivity` at some point...

```
@Module
abstract class ActivityBindingModule {
  @ContributesAndroidInjector
  abstract fun bindMainActivity(): MainActivity


  // ...that's not really how it works... :/
  @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = [(BaseActivityModule::class)])
  abstract fun bindBaseActivity(): BaseActivity
}
```

Using the above code you end up with some component to inject `MainActivity`, and some component to inject `BaseActivity`, but neither can inject "both". The error you receive is because `MainActivity` can't supply the `FragmentManager` it needs to inject in its parent `BaseActivity`. It's missing the module to do so. You only add the `BaseActivityModule` to your other component, to which the MainActivityComponent effectively has no access—hence the *cannot be provided* error.

Dagger always needs to inject the whole object. There is no partial injection, or injecting from multiple components at once. If a single component can't provide *all* the dependencies it needs you will get an error. Your `fun bindBaseActivity(): BaseActivity` is useless, because you will never use `BaseActivity`, but you will only use `MainActivity` or other subclasses of it. *Those* components need to be able to provide the dependencies of the BaseActivity as well.

---

If you want to inject dependencies in the BaseActivity you need to add a module that provides the necessary bindings. Your code should end up looking like the following:

```
@Module
abstract class ActivityBindingModule {
  @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = [BaseActivityModule::class, MainActivityModule::class])
  abstract fun bindMainActivity(): MainActivity

  // no BaseActivity component necessary
}

@Module
abstract class MainActivityModule {
  @Binds
  abstract fun bindBaseActivity(activity: MainActivity) : BaseActivity
}
```

This does the following things:

1. It adds `BaseActivityModule` to the MainActivityComponent, so that your base-dependencies can be provided by this component and `MainActivity` can be injected
2. It binds `MainActivity` in another module as your `BaseActivity` so that you can use that in your module and don't have to bind a FragmentManager for every activity you have

While you can reuse `BaseActivityModule` and add it to all of your activity implementations, you will have to add a module to bind the activity as a `BaseActivity` for every one of your activities.

There might be a more optimized approach, but that's the vanilla requirements for injecting subclasses.

Answer (score 1):

Main idea to understand that Dagger understands only top component/activity injection and doesn't see `BaseActivityComponent`

Alternative implementation to @David Medenjak solution is to simply include `BaseActivityModule` and inject `BaseActivity`:

```
@ActivityScope
@Subcomponent(modules = {MainActivityModule.class, BaseActivityModule.class} )
public interface PlayerActivityComponent {

    void inject(MainActivity activity);

    void inject(BaseActivity activity);
}
```

And you can inject your objects now both in `BaseActivity` and `MainActivity`

Comment: Are you sure you can inject into BaseActivity? It's abstract.

Comment: Last time I tried, it worked for me. Feel free to test and update if it doesn't work.